# how to make sympy simplify expressions llike (a**2 - 4*b)*sqrt(1/(a**2 - 4*b))

Tags: sympy

From other sympy code I obtain expressions like :

```
u = (a**2*sqrt(1/(a**2 - 4*b)) - a - 4*b*sqrt(1/(a**2 - 4*b)))/(2*(a**2 - 
4*b)*sqrt(1/(a**2 - 4*b)))
```

where a and b are sympy symbols. I tried

```
u = u.simplify(), u = u.expand() and u = simplify(str(u)),
```

to no avail,  the code does not change. How can I obtain the simplification of these kind of expresions?

Comment: The `a**2-4*b` looks a lot like a [2nd degree discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) , but there doesn't seem to be any way to leverage that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only attempting a manual simplification here, with some notes.

The cue was that the subexpression `a**2 - 4*b` shows up 4 times. I'm not sure how this could be extended to a more general method.

```py
from IPython.display import Math, display
from sympy import *

init_printing()
a,b,D=symbols('a b \Delta')

u = (a**2*sqrt(1/(a**2 - 4*b)) - a - 4*b*sqrt(1/(a**2 - 4*b)))/(2*(a**2 - 4*b)*sqrt(1/(a**2 - 4*b)))

D_ = a**2 - 4*b

r = []

r.append(latex(u))
u = u.subs(D_,D)
r.append(latex(u))
u = u.subs(2*D_, 2*D)
r.append(latex(u))
u = collect(u, 1/D)
r.append(latex(u))
u = u.subs(D_,D)
r.append(latex(u))
u = u.expand()
r.append(latex(u))
u = u.subs(D,D_)
r.append(latex(u))

display(Math(" \\Longrightarrow ".join(r)))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can use `ratsimp(radsimp(u))` to get the same result.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin O didn't know about radsimp and ratsimp but it works fine, thanks again for saving my day.

Comment: although Oscars solution is excellent, your answer is also valid and as a bonus gives an example of the use of LaTex, so I'll accept your answer